# Odoo - How to update non updateable records by XML

Tags: odoo

I have created a few companies under `res.company`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="True">
        <record id="partner_my_company_hk" model="res.partner" context="{'default_is_company': True}">
            <field name="name">My company HK</field>
            <field name="company_id" eval="None"/>
            <field name="customer" eval="False"/>
            <field name="is_company" eval="True"/>
            <field name="street"></field>
            <field name="city"></field>
            <field name="zip"></field>
            <field name="phone"></field>
            <field name="email">info@my_company.com</field>
            <field name="website">www.my_company.com</field>
            <field name="image" type="base64" file="base/static/img/res_company_logo.png"/>
        </record>

        <record id="partner_my_company_us" model="res.partner">
            <field name="name">My company US</field>
            <field name="company_id" eval="None"/>
            <field name="customer" eval="False"/>
            <field name="is_company" eval="True"/>
            <field name="street"></field>
            <field name="city"></field>
            <field name="zip"></field>
            <field name="phone"></field>
            <field name="email">info@my_company.com</field>
            <field name="website">www.my_company.com</field>
            <field name="image" type="base64" file="base/static/img/res_company_logo.png"/>
        </record>

        <record id="company_my_company_hk" model="res.company">
            <field name="name">My company HK</field>
            <field name="partner_id" ref="partner_my_company_hk"/>
            <field name="currency_id" ref="base.USD"/>
        </record>

        <record id="partner_my_company_hk" model="res.partner">
            <field name="company_id" ref="company_my_company_hk"/>
        </record>

        <record id="company_my_company_us" model="res.company">
            <field name="name">My company US</field>
            <field name="partner_id" ref="partner_my_company_us"/>
            <field name="currency_id" ref="base.USD"/>
        </record>

        <record id="partner_my_company_us" model="res.partner">
            <field name="company_id" ref="company_my_company_us"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

This is my original `res_users.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="0">
        <record id="base.user_admin" model="res.users">
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, ref('account.group_account_user'))]"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

So I want to set those 2 newly created 2 companies into `base.user_admin`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="0">
        <record id="base.user_admin" model="res.users">
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, ref('account.group_account_user'))]"/>

            <field name="company_id" ref="company_my_company_hk" />
            <field name="company_ids" eval="[(4, ref('company_my_company_hk')),(4, ref('company_my_company_us'))]" />
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

And it is not working. But when I uninstall the module and reinstall it works.

Why? I cannot uninstall the module just to make it work in the future. What are the limitations and how to bypass the limits?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the `noupdate` value on XML, change the desired fields and should take the change on `noupdate` back.

```xml
<!-- Allow updating on noupdate=True records -->
<function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
    <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
        <value
            eval="[('module', '=', 'base'), ('name', '=', 'user_admin')]" />
    </function>
    <value eval="{'noupdate': False}" />
</function>

<record id="base.user_admin" model="res.users">
    <!-- change fields here -->
</record>

<!-- Revoke noupdate change -->
<function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
    <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
        <value
            eval="[('module', '=', 'base'), ('name', '=', 'user_admin')]" />
    </function>
    <value eval="{'noupdate': True}" />
</function>
```

Comment: I've changed the title/subject of your question. Hopefully you're okay with it. It's a bit more general now.

Comment: I have a question. why the write method wraps the search method? Did the resource define this?

Comment: Can't answer that properly :/

Answer (score 1):

External ID `user_admin` in `base` has been marked as `noupdate`.

And `noupdate` cannot be overridden.

Unless I run

```sql
UPDATE ir_model_data SET noupdate=False WHERE name = 'user_admin' and module='base';
```

Otherwise I won't be able to update it when I upgrade the module

Comment: No you can do it in XML too. So it is possible on module update. I will write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

More refined solution to @CZoellner 's solution is:

```xml
<function name="toggle_noupdate" model="ir.model.data" eval="['res.users', ref('base.user_admin')]"/>
```