# Try to override(noupdate=1) email template in Odoo 12

Tags: overriding, odoo, odoo-12, email-templates

I am trying override base email template(noupdate=1) but, unable to override. Also, search for my issue but didn't get proper solution.

So, anybody can help me for this issue.

my code is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<odoo>
    <data noupdate="0">
        <!-- Email template for reset password -->
        <delete id="auth_signup.reset_password_email" model="mail.template"/>
        <record id="reset_password_email" model="mail.template">
           . . .
        </record>
        <!-- Email template for new users -->
        <delete id="auth_signup.set_password_email" model="mail.template"/>
        <record id="set_password_email" model="mail.template">
            . . .
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

This error comes when create new user:

```
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: auth_signup.reset_password_email
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Odoo - How to update non updateable records by XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403653/odoo-how-to-update-non-updateable-records-by-xml)

Comment: Do you have `auth_signup` in your module's dependencies?

Comment: It gives below error:

odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Invalid field 'module' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('module', '=', 'auth_signup') on mail_template (ctx: )>""

Comment: yes module is auth_signup

Answer (score -1):

well, you don't need to override the existing email template. you may need a new one. you could also delete the old one

```xml
<record id="reset_password_email" model="mail.template">
  <field name="name">Auth Signup: Reset Password</field>
  <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_users"/>
  <field name="subject">Password reset</field>
  <field name="email_from">"${object.company_id.name | safe}" &lt;${(object.company_id.email or user.email) | safe}&gt;</field>
  <field name="email_to">${object.email_formatted | safe}</field>
  <field name="body_html" type="html">
    <p>whatever email template you want & remember you could use OBJECT AS FOLLOWING</p>
    <span style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
      ${object.name}
    </span>
  </field>
  <field name="lang">${object.lang}</field>
  <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
  <field name="user_signature" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

please note that you custom template id would be names as `custom_module.reset_password_email` & it will replace `auth_signup.reset_password_email`.

or you could follow:
[Odoo - How to update non updateable records by XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403653/odoo-how-to-update-non-updateable-records-by-xml)